# From where to download GTK for codeblocks

Tags: windows, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I am new to GTK . This link is not working http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php
and when i downloaded it from other souce the codeblock is saying can't locate gtk.h in it.

Comment: What other source did you download it from?

Answer (score 1):

If you went to gtk.org you'd see the new page is http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php

To summarize use the [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/) project to install it.